# Q'thraaaa alien race in novel

Tags: story-identification, books

Does anyone know a book which features an alien race called the Q'thraaa? It's probably from the 1980s. I don't have any other information for it but it's driving me mad!

Comment: Can you think of *any* more details?  What was it about this book that makes you want to find it again?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think the answer to your second question could simply be a 'I liked it'

Comment: Also, how sure are you about that spelling? Three A's or four?

Comment: You sure it's not Qeng Ho?

Comment: I remember this, too! Though, I don't know if the spelling is accurate.

Comment: Yes not sure about the spelling. Andrew; I liked it! Don't remember qeng ho though..

Comment: No not qeng ho, looks like that was only published in 1999

Answer (score 5):

I thought of 2 possibilities based on similarities to the name you remember, one from the *sound* of the name, another based on the *look* of the name.
1. ***sound*** : *The Pride of Chanur* by C.J.Cherryh (1981) -- first book in the [Chanur series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chanur_novels). If you have a primarily auditory memory of the name, there are races called **Tc'a** and **Kif**, and lots of words with "kk" and "aah" sounds.
2. ***look*** : *A Matter for Men* by David Gerrold (1983) -- first book in the [The War Against the **Chtorr** series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_Against_the_Chtorr). I have a more visual memory, which is why "Q'thraaa" reminded me of reading the word **Chtorr** as the name for the aliens, and the word **Chtorran** in descriptions.
 :-)

UPDATE:
3. ***Alternate spelling*** : Alien race known as the  **K'Thraa** in *Earth Invaded* by Christopher Evans (1986) -- first book in [The Hood's Army trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hood's_Army_Trilogy). 
;-}